# UserForm animation gets stuck

Tags: excel, vba

Module LoadDots:

```
Option Explicit

'this function ensures the self-activating sub will stop if the UF has been closed
Public Function IsLoaded(form As String) As Boolean
Dim frm As Object
For Each frm In VBA.UserForms
    If frm.Name = form Then
        IsLoaded = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next frm
IsLoaded = False
End Function


Public Sub loadingdots()

If IsLoaded("LoadingInternet") = True Then
    If Len(LoadingInternet.DotLabelloading.Caption) = 4 Then
        LoadingInternet.DotLabelloading.Caption = "."
        DoEvents
    Else
        LoadingInternet.DotLabelloading.Caption = LoadingInternet.DotLabelloading.Caption & "."
        DoEvents
    End If
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "loadingdots"
    DoEvents
End If

End Sub
```

UserForm `LoadingInternet`:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

On Error Resume Next

Dim AppXCenter As Long, AppYCenter As Long
AppXCenter = Application.Left + (Application.Width / 2)
AppYCenter = Application.Top + (Application.Height / 2)
With Me
.StartUpPosition = 0
.Top = AppYCenter - (Me.Height / 2)
.Left = AppXCenter - (Me.Width / 2)
End With

subRemoveCloseButton Me

Call loadingdots

End Sub
```

If I call UserForm like this:

```
Sub asfafadfdsfdsfdsf()

  LoadingInternet.Show vbModeless
  
End Sub
```

animation is working.

However in this case I see only one dot (first one). Any ideas why so? Only first dot visible (no animation):

```
Sub CallCommercialMAIN()
    
    On Error Resume Next

    LoadingInternet.Show (vbModeless)
    DoEvents
    
        Commercial.Show (vbModeless)
    
    Unload LoadingInternet

End Sub
```

---

Here is what I am trying to achieve (used Wingdings font in this example):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of animation looks too complicated for me...

Try the next approach, please:

```
Sub DotAnimation()
   Dim i As Long, frm As Object
   Set frm = LoadingInternet
   If Not IsLoaded(frm.Name) Then Exit Sub
   frm.DotLabelloading.Caption = "."
   For i = 1 To 1000
        DoEvents
        Select Case i
            Case 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000
                frm.DotLabelloading.Caption = frm.DotLabelloading.Caption & "."
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

and `IsLoaded` function, modified a little:

```
Public Function IsLoaded(form As String) As Boolean
 Dim frm As Object
 For Each frm In VBA.UserForms
    If frm.Name = form Then
        If frm.Visible = True Then
            IsLoaded = True: Exit Function
        End If
    End If
 Next frm
End Function
```

If the above Sub does not work, try please, the next one, for a Button click event (from the form in discussion):

```
Private Sub CommandButtonX_Click()
 Dim i As Long
 Me.DotLabelloading.Caption = "."
 For i = 1 To 1000
    DoEvents
    Select Case i
        Case 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000
            Me.DotLabelloading.Caption = Me.DotLabelloading.Caption & "."
    End Select
 Next i
End Sub
```

In order to have a continuous animation loop you can use a recursive `Sub` like the following one. Of course, you can extend the number of dots per cycle or the dots apparition speed. You can also use an (API) Timer. I've just playing with iteration to check if the animation works:

```
Private Sub DotAnimation()
 Dim i As Long
 Static AnimNo As Long
 Me.DotLabelloading.Caption = "."
 For i = 1 To 1000
    DoEvents
    Select Case i
        Case 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000
            Me.DotLabelloading.Caption = Me.DotLabelloading.Caption & "."
    End Select
 Next i
 AnimNo = AnimNo + 1
 If AnimNo <= 4 Then
   DotAnimation
 Else
   AnimNo = 0
 End If
End Sub
```

And, instead of the existing code from `UserForm_Activate`, you must clear it and place only

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
  DoEvents
  DotAnimation
End Sub
```

I was afraid of a really infinite loop and I limited it to 4 cycles. See the `Static AnimNo` variable. After testing, you can remove it, or extend the cycles number to whatever you need...

Theoretically, `DoEvents` should allow you to work with the form in parallel...

Comment: While calling userform all dots are visible straight in the begging but no animation. Maybe I am doing something wrong. Investigating currently what may be the issue

Comment: @hatman: Is that happening when tried using the above code? I tested it and works animating the label dots...

Comment: After last edit no dots are visible, Label is empty. I will try it on new Workbook

Comment: Try, please putting the code in a button Click event (on the form). Doesn't it work neither? Without any preliminary checking. In fact, I will edit the answer and add it...

Comment: Button click works. Dots are loaded fast and then it stops. I guess I need to add loop inside loop? So that after all are loaded it will continue on and on? Also I wondering why it works on button click but does not work on `UserForm_Initialize`

Comment: @hatman: It cannot work in the `Initialize` event... But I think it will work in `UserForm_Activate` event, if convenient. This is fired after initialization...

Comment: It seems to be working in Activate. Now the question is how to create an infinite loop. Is If - For as in my example the only solution?

Comment: @hatman: You can do it using a recursive Sub. I will try posting an example...